# Return results less than two Sundays ago

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datediff

I have the below date column in a table.

TableA

```
WEEKENDDATE
 2/24/2019
 3/10/2019
 6/10/2019
```

How do I only return results from less than two Sundays ago using the where clause?

So, any date from column WEEKENDDATE that is greater than two Sundays ago would NOT show.

`select * from TableA where 1=1 --and`

Comment: Not hard to do, but you must give a very precise definition of "less than two Sundays ago". What if you run the query on a Sunday at 10 AM - what is "two Sundays ago" in that case? Also, by "less than two Sundays ago" do you mean "dates that are on or **after** two Sundays ago"? That really means "greater than" that date (of two Sundays ago), not "**less** than" the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
where weekenddate >= next_day(sysdate - interval '1' day, 'SUNDAY') - interval '14' day
```

(I'm not sure if you want 2 or three weeks in the past.)

That said, your dates all appear to be on Sundays, so this seems simpler:

```
where weekenddate >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '14' day
```

Comment: getting "invalid datetime field" from the keyword "week"